# Changeable element shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm building a website for a nutritionist in wordpress, where it has every patient area.

So I was thinking to make a section with a motivation youtube video and this code will be placed to every customer page.

Is there a way I can place for example [motivation_video] on the wordpress and that I could change the youtube link on my backend whenever I want? So I won't need to change all the pages.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your wordpress functions.php file place the following code with your modifications:

```
function video_function($atts, $content = null){
     $shortcode_return = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="video_url_here" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    return $shortcode_return;
 }
 add_shortcode('motivation_video','video_function');
```

Whenever you want a new video, just change the video_url_here